# ZFS Case Sensitivity is supposed to be settable post-creation, but it's 'read-only'

Tags: zfs, case-insensitive

According to [this Oracle document on Settable ZFS Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-2271/gazsd/index.html), `casesensitivity` is supposed to be a settable property post ZFS Pool creation but, regardless of the value I supply, I get a 'read-only' response:

```shellsession
$ sudo zfs set casesensitivity=caseinsensitive rpool/USERDATA
[sudo] password for kolin:
cannot set property for 'rpool/USERDATA': 'casesensitivity' is readonly
```

I understand that messing with case sensitivity on an existing dataset sounds pretty bonkers, but the current need outweighs the potential danger.

Answer (score 3):

Having read the casesensitivity section of the document you linked to numerous times, I do not see any sentence that implies that case sensitivity of the file system can be changed after it is set.

Ubuntu 20.04 uses [OpenZFS 0.8.3](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/releases/tag/zfs-0.8.3) by default, which does not make it easy to change the `casesensitivity` value after a pool has been created. It's even stated [in the ZFS manage for Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/zfs.8.html):

```
The following three properties cannot be changed after the file system  is  created, and
therefore, should be set when the file system is created. If the properties are not set
with the zfs create or zpool create commands, these properties are  inherited from the
parent dataset. If the parent dataset lacks these properties due to having been created
prior to these features being supported, the new file system will have the default values
for these properties.

casesensitivity=sensitive | insensitive | mixed

    Indicates whether the file name matching algorithm used by the file system should be
    case-sensitive, case-insensitive, or allow a combination of both styles of matching.
    The default value for the casesensitivity property is sensitive. Traditionally, UNIX
    and POSIX file systems have case-sensitive file names.

    The mixed value for the casesensitivity property indicates that the  file  system  can
    support  requests  for  both  case-sensitive  and  case-insensitive matching behavior.
    Currently, case-insensitive matching behavior on a file  system  that  supports  mixed
    behavior is limited to the Solaris CIFS server product. For more information about the
    mixed value behavior, see the Solaris ZFS Administration Guide.
```

Changing of the `casesensitivity` property is not permitted for a number of reasons. Assuming a file system was `sensitive` or `mixed` and suddenly set as `insensitive`, there would be the potential for name conflicts:

```
$ ll

-rw-r--r-- 1 jason jason   220 Feb 25  2020 doc.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jason jason  3812 Mar 24  2021 DOC.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jason jason   220 Feb 25  2020 Doc.txt
```

After being set as `insensitive`, which file gets returned? By default, an `insensitive` index will store everything in lower-case, meaning that you will lose access to `DOC.txt` which is larger, more recent, and *probably* the text file you wanted.

Another reason is overall performance. If a file system needs to handle situations where case sensitivity can be altered at will, it will need to track and manage case conflicts with every file interaction, even if the person using ZFS has no intention on changing the `casesensitivity` property. Disallowing the change helps the development team optimise indexes to keep lookups fast.

The last reason (that I'll mention) has to do more with people than technology. We – as a species – excel at creating our own problems and blaming everyone else for the hassles that immediately follow. Rather than have forum after forum filled with people complaining that entire directories of critical data are no longer accessible, it's sometimes better to forbid an action up front. People who *really* want to change the case sensitivity will learn how to access the hidden `.zfs` directory and modify the properties manually and panic when the ZFS Pool crashes but, for everyone else, they'll have to do things differently, which is what I suggest you do, as well.

Rather than change the case sensitivity for the current ZFS Pool, save yourself a world of frustration and create a new ZFS Pool and allocate some storage to it. Ensure it's set as being case insensitive from the beginning, and you'll be good.

For example:

```
sudo rpool create isamba /dev/sdc -o casesensitivity=insensitive
```